# Conic pencils and conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have a problem in understanding the following solution to a problem regarding conic pencils.

**EXERCISE**

Let $F$ be the conic pencil in which every conic section $Γ$:

0.1. $P = (0, 1) \in Γ$

0.2. $Q = (0, 0) \in Γ$

0.3. $Γ$ is tangent to $r : x+y-1=0$ in $P$

0.4. $Γ$ is tangent to $s : y=0$ in $Q$

Determine the conic section $C_i \in F$ that satisfies the following condition $i$:

1. $C_1$ is a parabola
2. $R = (-1,1) \in C_2$
3. $S=(1,1) \in C_3$

**SOLUTION**

To generate $F$, let’s use two conics:

- The product of $r$ and $s$
- The line $t$ that satisfies $P, Q \in t$, counted two times

So we get the following equation:
$tx^2 + y(x+y-1)=0$

The only problem with writing $F$ with “affine coordinates” is that we exclude the possibility to find $x^2=0$, but since it doesn’t satisfy any condition, it doesn’t matter.

*And then the exercise continues by finding $C_1, C_2, C_3$…*

**MY QUESTIONS**

**Q.1** How does the solution generate F immediately? I wouldn’t know how to get an equation for F, except by making a system with 4 equations, each one for one of the conditions from 0.1 to 0.4. But since it seems that the solution is way faster, I wonder how to do it and if this way of generating conic pencils can be used for other exercises.

**Q.2** What does “affine coordinates” mean in this context? Does it mean that we already applied an affine change of coordinates? Why does i timply that we exclude $x^2=0$

- Note that I’m not asking to solve points 1, 2 and 3 of the exercise, because I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have found the answer to my own question.

Conic bundles can be written in the form $kΓ_1 + hΓ_2$ where $k, h\in\mathbb{R}$ are real parameters and $Γ_1, Γ_2$ are two conic sections. So, conic bundles are generated by two conics.

Now, I can try to choose two conic sections that generate the conic bundle $F$, and then impose conditions 1 (or 2, or 3) to find a value of the parameter which gives me the conic section.

To try and find those two “generators”, I have to know the types of ocnic sections.
Because saying “$F$ is tangent to $r$ in $P$“ is equal to saying that, in P, $F$ is exactly $r$, by applying the same reasoning for $s$ we find that a generator $Γ_1$ could be the product of $r$ and $s$, which is a type of conic section named “pair of distinct incident real lines”.

Then, we know that a line that satisfies the condition 0.1, 0.2 is $x=0$: if we count it two times, so $x^2=0$, we notice it’s a conic section named “double real line”, and it still satisfies the conditions.

Now, we have the equation of $F$: $$kx^2+hy(x+y-1)=0$$ We can verify that this equations satisfies 0.1, 0.2 (how do we verify that it also satisfies 0.3 and 0.4?)
We can, additionally, delete the parameter $h$ of $y(x+y-1)$, because by doing that we only exclude the conic section $Γ_3: x^2=0$ (since there is no value of $k$ for which we can find $x^2=0$).
Thus we have found the equation found by the solution of my question.

Comment: Double line $x^2=0$ also satisfies 0.3 and 0.4, because it has a double point in common with the tangent lines. You can see it as the union of a degenerate ellipse (segment $PQ$) and a degenerate hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

The conic bundle can be represented by the general equation

$A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0 $

Applying the first two conditions, we get

$ C + E + F = 0 \hspace{15pt}(1) $

$ F = 0 \hspace{15pt}(2)$

Now compute the derivative $y'$ as follows

$ 2 A x + B (y + x y' ) +2 C y y' + D + E y' = 0 $

Now the line $x + y - 1 = 0 $ has a slope of $y' = -1$, therefore substituting $P(0, 1)$ into the above, one gets

$ B (1) + 2 C (1)(-1) + D - E = 0 $

i.e.

$ B - 2 C + D - E = 0 \hspace{15pt}(3)$

The line $y = 0 $ has a slope of $ y' = 0 $ , and by substituting $Q(0,0)$, we get

$ D = 0 \hspace{15pt}(4)$

Solving the system of linear equations $(1)-(4)$ yields,

$(A, B, C, D, E, F) = t (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + s (0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0) $

Now for $C_1$, the only requirement is $ 4 A C - B^2 = 0 $

Hence,

$ 4 t (-s) - (-s)^2 = 0 $

Since $s \ne 0 $, then $ 4 t + s = 0 $

i.e.  $ s = - 4 t $, thus

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = (t , 4 t , 4 t, 0, -4 t, 0 )$

Dividing by $t$, gives the required parabola

$ x^2 + 4 x y + 4 y^2 - 4 y = 0 $

For $C_2$ the point $R(-1, 1)$ is the on the conic, so

$t (-1)^2 - s (1)(-1) - s (1)^2 + s (1) = 0$

Hence $ t + s = 0 $, from which,

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = t (1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0 ) $

Thus the equation of the conic $C_2 $ is

$ x^2 + x y + y^2 - y = 0 $

Finally, for $C_3$, the point $S(1, 1)$ is on the conic, so

$ t (1)^2 - s (1)(1) - s (1)^2 + s (1) = 0 $

Hence,

$ t - s = 0 $, from which

$ (A, B, C, D, E, F) = t (1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0 ) $

And the equation of $C_3$ is

$ x^2 - x y - y^2 + y = 0 $

Comment: thanks, but in **Q.1** i wrote that doing a system with all the equations was not the solution I was looking for, because I already knew how to solve the exercise that way, and it looked like the solution of the exercise got the equation of $F$ in a faster way. I was wondering if there actually was such “faster way”.

Comment: I don't see a faster way.