# Generators of conic pencil

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I’m studying linear algebra and conic sections.

**CONTEXT AND TYPE OF EXERCISE**

By conic pencil $F$ I mean the set of all conic sections that result from a linear combination of two conic sections $Γ_1, Γ_2$, that are said to generate $F$.

Conic pencils can be written in the form $$F: k_1Γ_1 + k_2Γ_2$$ where $k_1, k_2\in\mathbb{R}$ are real parameters and $Γ_1, Γ_2$ are two conic sections. So, conic pencils are generated by two conics.

Since the general equation for a conic is: $$Γ: ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx+ ey + f=0$$ we have a maximum of 6 parameters to determine a unique conic section, and we determine those parameters by using some conditions.

The type of exercises I’m interested in is the following:

1. You are given 5 indipendent conditions.
2. You use 4 conditions to choose the right conic sections $Γ_1$ and $Γ_2$ that generate a conic pencils $F$, so that you get an equation of type $F: k_1Γ_1 + k_2Γ_2$.

- Often they’re degenerate conic sections, since they’re simpler to see.

3. You say that one of the two generators, say $Γ_1$, doesn’t satisfy one of the 5 conditions: so we just delete the paramater $k_2$, because the fact that $Γ_1$ cannot be obtained for any value of $k_1$ doesn’t bother us (since $Γ_1$ isn’t a solution)
4. Thus, you have just one parameter left to determine the conic $Γ \in F$ that you’re searching (the equation is now of form $F: kΓ_1 + Γ_2$). You use the 5th condition to determine $k$ and you’re done.

- Note that point 3. and 4. aren’t really needed for question 1, but I think they help understand the kind of exercise.

**QUESTION 1**

My question is: how do we know that the chosen conic sections generate the conic bundle that we’re searching for, that satisfies the first 4 conditions, except by “brute forcing” all the possible generators and testing the 4 conditions?

Note that I want a method that is general, so that works for other conditions, not only points that are in a conic sections (for example, there might be “tangent to line” conditions, etc).

See examples below to understand my doubts.

**EXAMPLE 1**

Write the equation of a conic section Γ that satisfies the following: $$ P_1=(1, 0) \in Γ, P_2=(1, 1) \in Γ, P_3=(3, 0) \in Γ, P_4=(3, 3) \in Γ, P_5=(4,1) \in Γ$$

Solution (point 1.-2.): we choose $Γ_1: (x-1)(x-3)=0$, which satisfies $P_1, P_3 \in Γ$, and $Γ_2: y(x-y)=0$ which satisfies $P_2, P_4 \in Γ$.

My doubts: am I right, if I say that the only way to say that $Γ_1$ and $Γ_2$ actually generate the “right” conic pencil (and “right” in this context means “that includes the conic section that satisfies the 5th condition) is to see if the conic pencil satisfies the 5th condition? Are there any tricks to “already know” when you’re picking wrong generators of the pencil?

- In this case, we can see that the generators made by the solution satisfies all $P_i \in Γ$ because, if we plug in $P_i$ in $(x-1)(x-3)+k(y(x-y)=0$ it’s true.

For example, if I choose the conic sections $Γ_3: (y-x-1)(x-3)$ which satisfies $P_1, P_3 \in Γ$ and $Γ_4: y(x-y)$ which satisfies $P_2, P_4 \in Γ$, are they wrong just because I can see that the conic pencil $(y-x-1)(x-3) + ky(x-y)$ doesn’t actually satisfy $(1,1) \in Γ$? Because if I can’t see it before, it seems to me that I could get stuck in “trying a lot of different lines and never getting the right combination”. Am I missing something?

**QUESTION 2**

I don’t really understand point 3., it doesn’t really seem to make sense to me, but I found it in many solutions of this type of exercises. Can someone explain better why we really can just “avoid” one parameter, and why the outcome of that is really just excluding one of the generator and not excluding also other possible conic sections of the conic pencil that might be solutions?

**EXAMPLE 2 (for question 2, asked by a comment)**

Write the equation of a conic section $γ$ that satisfies the following: $$ P_1=(0, 0) \in γ, P_2=(1, 1) \in γ, P_3=(1, 2) \in γ, P_4=(2, 3) \in γ, P_5=\left(-\frac{1}{2},0\right) \in γ$$

We choose to build the conic pencil that satisfies every condition except $P_4 \in γ$. The first generator is the conic section $Γ_5: y(x-1) = 0$ which contains $P_1P_5$ and $P_2P_3$. The second generator is the conic section $Γ_6: (x-y)(4x-3y+2)=0$ which contains $P_1P_2$ and $P_3P_5$. The resulting conic pencil, for the solution, has equation $F: y(x-1) + t(x-y)(4x-3y+2)=0$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$. As you can see, there is no parameter on $Γ_5$.

**APPENDIX**

See my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614936/843088).

Comment: "We have six independent conditions." Well, they aren't really independent. If you multiply $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ by a non-zero scalar, you get the same conic. And at least one of $a,b,c$ must be non-zero for it to be a conic section. And there are additional conditions to make sure the conic is not degenerate. So the possible conics are parameterized by a subset of $\mathbb RP^5,$ the real projective plane of dimension $5.$

Comment: "... where $k,h\in\mathbb R.$" Did you mean $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb R?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I will correct that. By “they aren’t really indipendent”, you mean that it really depends on how many parameters are non-zero, right? So my error is in saying that they’re (always) independent when it really depends by the case

Comment: It is unclear really what a conic bundle is in this definition. Is it just a tuple $(k_1,\Gamma_1,k_2,\Gamma_2)?$ Is it meant to have other properties? Presumably, the notation would imply $$k_2\Gamma_2+k_1\Gamma_1=k_1\Gamma_1+k_2\Gamma_2?$$

Comment: Regarding your question: No, I mean there are lots of different 6-tuples $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ which yield the same conic section.

Comment: You should mention your connected [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614936/305862) asked yesterday in order that people answering you don't start again from scratch.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews doesn’t have that to do more with the fact the an equation of a conic is unique only unless a scalar multiplication? I don’t understand what it has to do with independency of conditions

Comment: @JeanMarie I thought that it could be better to ask the question in a different way, since the only answer I got to the previous question was one I explicitly said I didn’t want. I’ll include it anyway

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you can explain to me what was the point you’re trying to make, I’ll be glad. I edited my question hopefully so it’s  more clear.

Comment: Probably you'd better call it a [PENCIL of conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)#Pencil_of_conics), because a [conic bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_bundle) is something different.

Comment: And then, if you want to generate the pencil of conics having in common four points $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, $P_4$, just start from two degenerate conics containing those points, e.g. $\Gamma_1=$ (lines $P_1P_2$) (line $P_3P_4$) and $\Gamma_2=$ (line $P_1P_3$) (line $P_2P_4$).

Comment: @Intelligentipauca ohhh thanks, that’s why I couldn’t find anything on what I wanted to know. Is there a general method for also other conditions, not only for a conic pencil for which we have the base points? And can you help me also on question 2?

Comment: Do you have another example of #3, in addition to the one in your previous question? Because, as I wrote there in a comment, that double line did satisfy the tangency requirement, even if in a strange way.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca see example 2

Comment: In $k_1\Gamma_1+k_2\Gamma_2$ it's only the ratio $k_1/k_2$ that matters. Hence setting $k_1=1$ you get all conics in the pencil, except the one obtained by setting $k_1=0$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca oh ok of course, thanks. If you want to put it as an answer I’ll accept, but I have another question (last one): so is it really like I said, that to find the generators of a conic pencil that satisfies $x$ conditions, you just have to try some conic sections and verify if the generated conic pencil satisfies the $x$ conditions for some value of the parameter(s)? (except from the case where you have 4 base points, which is simpler and quite generalizable, as you explained?)

Comment: But which other kind of conditions do you have in mind, beyond passing through a point? Tangency with a line is equivalent at having a double point of intersection.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I just thought there might be some other conditions, but yeah now that you’re pointing it out I’m trying to do something too vague. Thanks anyway.